# How do I retrieve information off Yelp using jSoup?

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup, element

I'm currently trying to extract the names of all given companies upon a particular yelp search, and store the results into an array. Here's what I have going:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class YelpScraper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=new+jersey&ns=1";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("biz-name js-analytics-click");
        
        for (Element element : elements)
        {
            System.out.println(elements.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```html
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/darios-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="resfu-JNLUKR3l82D5W7-A"><span>Dario’s Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/sushi-house-21-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="vMpJRWxm71XSBnWL9XfYpQ"><span>Sushi House 21</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/burger-walla-newark" data-hovercard-id="JmPZ-AyewjQPIJkKbkU0dA"><span>Burger Walla</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hobbys-delicatessen-and-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="-dEkFa3N6SXLahAMBAM8EA"><span>Hobby’s Delicatessen &amp; Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/krugs-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="YhiUGWjAB1y7reqoKLWCow"><span>Krug’s Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/mcwhorter-barbecue-newark" data-hovercard-id="6xf4H2rOCtUIhyMgazRsnA"><span>McWhorter Barbecue</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/spanish-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="muXH1f3nwoSgWB3KN-rAfA"><span>Spanish Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/casa-d-paco-newark" data-hovercard-id="iIJ-dWgYcZTewVGJyP6EfQ"><span>Casa d’Paco</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hero-king-handcrafted-sandwiches-newark" data-hovercard-id="hzwE2ub1J7fTwJDjTJwksA"><span>Hero King Handcrafted Sandwiches</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/the-green-chicpea-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="bDWWtSm-8uoW9_urjMCzTA"><span>The Green Chicpea</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/darios-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="resfu-JNLUKR3l82D5W7-A"><span>Dario’s Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/sushi-house-21-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="vMpJRWxm71XSBnWL9XfYpQ"><span>Sushi House 21</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/burger-walla-newark" data-hovercard-id="JmPZ-AyewjQPIJkKbkU0dA"><span>Burger Walla</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hobbys-delicatessen-and-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="-dEkFa3N6SXLahAMBAM8EA"><span>Hobby’s Delicatessen &amp; Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/krugs-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="YhiUGWjAB1y7reqoKLWCow"><span>Krug’s Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/mcwhorter-barbecue-newark" data-hovercard-id="6xf4H2rOCtUIhyMgazRsnA"><span>McWhorter Barbecue</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/spanish-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="muXH1f3nwoSgWB3KN-rAfA"><span>Spanish Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/casa-d-paco-newark" data-hovercard-id="iIJ-dWgYcZTewVGJyP6EfQ"><span>Casa d’Paco</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hero-king-handcrafted-sandwiches-newark" data-hovercard-id="hzwE2ub1J7fTwJDjTJwksA"><span>Hero King Handcrafted Sandwiches</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/the-green-chicpea-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="bDWWtSm-8uoW9_urjMCzTA"><span>The Green Chicpea</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/darios-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="resfu-JNLUKR3l82D5W7-A"><span>Dario’s Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/sushi-house-21-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="vMpJRWxm71XSBnWL9XfYpQ"><span>Sushi House 21</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/burger-walla-newark" data-hovercard-id="JmPZ-AyewjQPIJkKbkU0dA"><span>Burger Walla</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hobbys-delicatessen-and-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="-dEkFa3N6SXLahAMBAM8EA"><span>Hobby’s Delicatessen &amp; Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/krugs-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="YhiUGWjAB1y7reqoKLWCow"><span>Krug’s Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/mcwhorter-barbecue-newark" data-hovercard-id="6xf4H2rOCtUIhyMgazRsnA"><span>McWhorter Barbecue</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/spanish-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="muXH1f3nwoSgWB3KN-rAfA"><span>Spanish Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/casa-d-paco-newark" data-hovercard-id="iIJ-dWgYcZTewVGJyP6EfQ"><span>Casa d’Paco</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hero-king-handcrafted-sandwiches-newark" data-hovercard-id="hzwE2ub1J7fTwJDjTJwksA"><span>Hero King Handcrafted Sandwiches</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/the-green-chicpea-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="bDWWtSm-8uoW9_urjMCzTA"><span>The Green Chicpea</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/darios-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="resfu-JNLUKR3l82D5W7-A"><span>Dario’s Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/sushi-house-21-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="vMpJRWxm71XSBnWL9XfYpQ"><span>Sushi House 21</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/burger-walla-newark" data-hovercard-id="JmPZ-AyewjQPIJkKbkU0dA"><span>Burger Walla</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hobbys-delicatessen-and-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="-dEkFa3N6SXLahAMBAM8EA"><span>Hobby’s Delicatessen &amp; Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/krugs-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="YhiUGWjAB1y7reqoKLWCow"><span>Krug’s Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/mcwhorter-barbecue-newark" data-hovercard-id="6xf4H2rOCtUIhyMgazRsnA"><span>McWhorter Barbecue</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/spanish-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="muXH1f3nwoSgWB3KN-rAfA"><span>Spanish Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/casa-d-paco-newark" data-hovercard-id="iIJ-dWgYcZTewVGJyP6EfQ"><span>Casa d’Paco</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hero-king-handcrafted-sandwiches-newark" data-hovercard-id="hzwE2ub1J7fTwJDjTJwksA"><span>Hero King Handcrafted Sandwiches</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/the-green-chicpea-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="bDWWtSm-8uoW9_urjMCzTA"><span>The Green Chicpea</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/darios-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="resfu-JNLUKR3l82D5W7-A"><span>Dario’s Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/sushi-house-21-newark-2" data-hovercard-id="vMpJRWxm71XSBnWL9XfYpQ"><span>Sushi House 21</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/burger-walla-newark" data-hovercard-id="JmPZ-AyewjQPIJkKbkU0dA"><span>Burger Walla</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/hobbys-delicatessen-and-restaurant-newark" data-hovercard-id="-dEkFa3N6SXLahAMBAM8EA"><span>Hobby’s Delicatessen &amp; Restaurant</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/krugs-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="YhiUGWjAB1y7reqoKLWCow"><span>Krug’s Tavern</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/mcwhorter-barbecue-newark" data-hovercard-id="6xf4H2rOCtUIhyMgazRsnA"><span>McWhorter Barbecue</span></a>
<a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/spanish-tavern-newark" data-hovercard-id="muXH1f3nwoSgWB3KN-rAfA"><span>Spanish Tavern</span></a>
```

As you can see, it outputs the HTML code of that class, and what I want is simply the name of the business. How I can do it differently?

Clearly the `getElementsByClass()` method is not what I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

You can either traverse the element's children you have or use a more fine grained selection in the first place.  I changed your selection to return the spans that contain the title and using the text() method it returns the text inside the span tags.

```
Elements elements = document.select(".indexed-biz-name span");
for (Element element : elements) 
{
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Comment: Hey wow, thanks! Works like a charm! I actually just picked up jSoup yesterday. If you wouldn't mind, could you just explain the syntax for the select() method? From what I can see, you would always start off with . and then the class name followed by the tags?